# Python: Triple Double Quote String format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting the following error, how should I fix it?

**KeyError: 'a'
Process finished with exit code 1**

```
s = """
a b c {a}
""".format({'a':'123'})

print s
```

Comment: `format` takes keyword arguments, not a dict.

Comment: or you can unpack your `dict`, `**{'a':'123'}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass in the arguments by name `.format(a=123)` or use [`format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) which expects a dictionary:

```
s = """
a b c {a}
""".format_map({'a':'123'})
```

Comment: Not much point to use `format_map` if the mapping is just a normal dict.

Comment: @wim That's correct, but if you got a dict why unpack it and pass it to `format` when you could also use `format_map`?

Answer (score 3):

Named formatting variables must be passed by name:

```
>>> s = """
... a b c {a}
... """.format(a=123)
>>> print(s)

a b c 123
```

If you're providing a dict of data, you can "unpack" the names:

```
>>> d = {'a': 123}
>>> s = """
... a b c {a}
... """.format(**d)
>>> print(s)

a b c 123
```

Comment: Another option if you're using Python 3.6 is to use f-strings.

Comment: That is only an option if the data comes from a name that's in scope.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `format` method for strings incorrectly. `format` requires that you pass in keyword arguments when you want to substitute names inside a string.

The correct form to use the method in your case would be the following:

```
s = """
a b c {a}
""".format(a='123')

print s
```

However if you do want to pass in a dictionary, then you can unpack it into keyword arguments by prepending `**` before the dictionary itself. This will unpack the dictionary into the the keyword argument of `a='123'` like the code above.

Please read more about Python strings and the string format method [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).